# Lazarus утечки памяти

Tags: lazarus

Я использую Lazarus версии 2.0.6(последняя на данный момент) под Linux.
Подскажите хоть 1 полностью рабочий способ поиска утечек памяти.

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,48919.0.html

Мне ответили на их форуме, что надо пользоваться другим менеджером памяти и посоветовали каким конкретно.

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck
```

Компилировать нужно с `uses cmem`.

Comment: Лучше скопировать основную информацию сюда, можно как цитату